# Is there a Windows store app control for expanding items?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am looking for a user control that implements the behavior that can be seen in various settings related pages in Windows 8 (e.g. in "PC Settings"\"PC and devices"\"Devices"): a list consisting of icons and a label, where an item is expanded when clicked upon, showing a button that provides an item related action.

Is there a suitable control available for Windows store apps? If not, what would be the most efficient way to implement this behavior?

Comment: I think it's just a `<StackPanel>` with individual element's Visibility set to collapse or visible.

Comment: It's a pretty broad question, there's multiple ways this could be done from the sounds of it, and if it's targeting windows store apps I'd maybe pull off the wpf tags since the controls/xaml could be a little different.

Comment: I have tried with StackPanel, but apart from requiring repetitive UI code, the expansion is not animated like in the mentioned lists.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something similar to TreeView in [WinrtXAMLToolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) ?

Comment: You are right, what I am looking for is similar to a tree view. But without arrows and allowing only a single item to be expanded. The TreeView in WinRTXAMLToolkit was a good tip, but apparently it cannot really be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FlyOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx) component.
Also you can find "in list flyout example" on internet.

Comment: Flyouts are always on top of everything and therefore do not shift other elements down. No exactly like the lists I mentioned.